# JavaFX WebView get/set inner/outer HTML in org.w3c.dom.Element;

Tags: javafx

I'm using a JavaFX HTMLEditor with webview. I have the following objects (the names are self explanatory)

```
private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

// for manipulating the html structure of the editor
WebView webView;
WebEngine webEngine;

// for accessing the document
HTMLDocumentImpl htmlDocImpl;
```

I'm trying to avoid building large strings to pass long functions into

```
webEngine.executeScript();
```

So I've been grabbing the HTML from the document by adding listeners to the webEngine, storing the document in htmlDocImpl, then accessing the DOM that way, for example this adds a mouse listener to the webEngine, and I set htmlDocImpl at this point

```
    webEngine.documentProperty().addListener((observable, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
        htmlDocImpl = (HTMLDocumentImpl) newDoc;
        htmlDocImpl.setOnmousemove(event -> {
        
            MouseEvent mouseE = (MouseEvent) event;
            activeMouseElem = htmlDocImpl.elementFromPoint(
                    (int)mouseE.getClientX(),
                    (int)mouseE.getClientY()
            );
            //System.out.println(activeMouseElem.toString());
        });
    });
```

This gives me access to the DOM in the webEngine. Then I manipulate the nodes using these objects:

```
org.w3c.dom.Element;
org.w3c.dom.Node;
```

The problem is, I can't figure out using this method how i can possibly get or set the inner HTML of these objects. I can do things like add children, remove elements, etc, but I need to be able to set their HTML! I cant find any methods that do this. The only way i can figure to modify HTML directly is with Javascript inside .executeScript().

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how this is done. Thank you.

Comment: Guessing: `activeMouseElem.setAttribute("innerHTML",  " ... ")` ?

Comment: lol duh. ok thank you

Comment: Uhm that doesnt actually work, I just get null every time i try it. For example activeMouseElem.getAttribute("innerHTML") returns null

Comment: As I said, it was just a guess.

Comment: Ah my bad you did say "guess"